# Getting stuck after updating google play service version

Tags: android, android-studio

Android studio getting stuck when run project after updating google play service version --> `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.+'`
Please guide.

Thanks

Comment: use  `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.+`

Answer (score 1):

Avoid calling `+`

**Don't**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.+'
```

**Do**

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0' //7.8.0 //7.3.0
```

Comment: than the above i would suggest you use only  the required components of the playservices individually

Comment: @war_Hero indeed indeed .

Comment: Why Avoid calling + ?

Comment: @kishore jethava Because `+` indicates that any version higher than `7.x` will do. A different version could possibly break your app. For reading: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I have used this  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0' but it's return error like theme already exists.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Goto this link :- http://storage5.static.itmages.com/i/16/0315/h_1458048273_6092397_b3f3d80924.jpeg

Comment: `build tool 22.0.1` then Clean project -> Rebuild Project

Comment: Run project after updating google play service version getting stuck entire PC.

Comment: I have try above solution but still getting stuck.

Comment: @PatelHiren Did you fix this yet ?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya No not yet

Comment: Take much time to build project and during build computer getting stuck.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya build.gradle goto this link http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1458119452.jpg

Comment: Call `buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"`